# Using ng-options within a directive and getting options data from injected service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I’ve create a custom directive that contains a select input field.

I’m using ng-options to populate the select options and I'm currently passing in the data for the options using an `options` attribute bound to an isolate scope. See below.

```html
<script>
  recManagerApp.directive(myDirective, function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: '/templates/directives/mydirective.html',
      scope: {
        mySelectedValue: "=",
        options : "="
      }
    };
  });
</script>

<my-directive my-selected-value="usersValue" options="myDataService.availbleOptions"></my-directive>

<div>
  <select data-ng-model="mySelectedValue" data-ng-options="item for item in options">
    <option value="">Select something</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The above works as expected, correctly populates the options, selects the correct value and has two-way binding to the property in the parent scope.

However, I’d rather not pass in the options using an attribute on the my-directive element and instead inject in a service (myDataService) that can provide the data for the ng-options. However, when I try this (various ways) no options are created, despite the service being injected correctly and the data being available. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

```
recManagerApp.directive(myDirective, function (myDataService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/templates/directives/mydirective.html',
        scope: {
            mySelectedValue: "=",
            options : myDataService.availableOptions
        }
    };
});
```

Thanks

Mat

Comment: I think you mean to set `options` in the link function. There you have access to the scope and to `myDataService`. The scope property of the directive definition object is only for binding parent scope to isolated scope with `=`, `&`, or `@`. Also remember to update the `options` value in the HTML attribute. If you can't work it out, please create a plnkr so we can pinpoint the issue!

Comment: You could also just use a controller in either the directive or the template of the directive and fetch the options there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, you have several options (as pointed out in the comments):

#### 1. create controller for the directive

In you directive's template, use a controller, i.e.

```
<div ng-controller="SelectController">
  <!-- your select with the ngOptions -->
</div>
```

and create the `SelectController` as a regular controller:

```
var app = angular.module("app.controllers", [])

app.controller("SelectController", ['$scope', 'myDataService', function(scope, service) {
  scope.options = service.whatEverYourServiceDoesToProvideThis()
}]);
```

You can also give your directive a controller, which works just the same:

```
recManagerApp.directive(myDirective, function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/templates/directives/mydirective.html',
        scope: {
            mySelectedValue: "=",
        },
        controller: ['$scope', 'myDataService', function(scope, service) {
          scope.options = service.whatEverYourServiceDoesToProvideThis()
        }]
    };
});
```

#### 2. injecting it into the directive and using it within link

```
recManagerApp.directive(myDirective, function (myDataService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/templates/directives/mydirective.html',
        scope: {
            mySelectedValue: "="
        },
        link: function(scope) {
          scope.options = myDataService.whatEverYourServiceDoesToProvideThis()
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: That's excellent, thanks. I had already tried option 2 with the injected service and the link function but had left the options property in my isolate scope which prevented it from working. Thanks again to you all for your speedy responses.